# Some objects appear black with lighting in render view

Tags: texturing, shaders, lighting

I’m trying to figure out what is causing objects to appear black in render view or when rendered.

[image]

I have applied identical texture/shader to all objects.

To rule out common issues such as blocking, lights being disabled, clamp, objects size vs light, I added an area lighting to cover all objects at the same distance

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have included the blender file.
[Link to blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rO5LPW2Mtnl4FUpkZLfT49PAfLPbRE99/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning off Auto Smooth under the Context tab.
[image]

Comment: Thank you @lukas !!! Someone else just told me to clear custom split normals data in object data properties and it also worked! Looks like I'm going to explore some new sections to have a better understanding on why those affect it. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of split normals. Click on *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*:

[image]