# My alembic file shows full black in cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders

It doesnt matter what material I apply, its just full black when rendered, or when shown in rendered viewport, cant even see the corners and edges of the objects, when I enter shading viewport you can see the material, but on the rendered viewport It just doesnt have any texture.
However, when rendered in eevee it has the material, I have no idea why this can happen, I can provide the alembic file if needed. I have opened it in different PC's and it has the same problem[[image: This is how it shows ][1]]

Comment: Material view only shows your materials behavior. Rendered view shows your entire scene. That means for example if your scene doesn't have lights, you won't see anything in rendered while everything is fine in material view.

Comment: Related? [Some objects appear black with lighting in render view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/245338/78972)

Comment: I do have lights, I even have put diferent objects to the left, right, above and under the object, with the same material, and they do show in rendered view/render, but the object I am trying to put the material to just doesnt, its full black